# How to format data.frame?

Tags: r, bioinformatics

How can i reformat the data.frame df1 based on the GeneID. Have to group the table based on common GeneID. also i want to strsplit the position

df1 =

```
GeneID  Common Organism Name        Position    
    3   mouse   10090   Acadm   Chr5:26082574-26089291(-)   
    3   human   9606    ACADM   Chr5:15028950-15032998(-)   
    6   mouse   10090   Acat1   Chr5:25999022-26004798(-)   
    6   human   9606    ACAT1   Chr5:15471699-15477027(-)   
    7   human   9606    NLN Chr5:26257691-26264308(+)   
    8   mouse   10090   canct1  Chr5:14910122-14914899(-)   
    9   mouse   9606    Gm10220 Chr5:25936465-25943267(-)   
    9   mouse   9606    Gm10354 Chr5:25949797-25954344(-)   
    9   mouse   9606    Gm1979  Chr5:11594913-11599784(+)   
    9   human   10090   TRIL    Chr7:28953358-28958413(-)
```

expected out put

```
Gene.ID M.Gene  M.Chr M.start   M.end      H.Gene H.Chr H.start     H.end
    3   Acadm   5   26082574    26089291    ACADM   5   15028950    15032998
    6   Acat1   5   25999022    26004798    ACAT1   5   15471699    15477027
    7   NA      NA  NA          NA           NLN    5   26257691    26264308
    8   canct1  5   14910122    14914899     NA       NA    NA      NA
    9   Gm10220 5   25936465    25943267    TRIL    7   28953358    28958413
    9   Gm10354 5   25949797    25954344    TRIL    7   28953358    28958413
    9   Gm1979  5   1159491     11599784    TRIL    7   28953358    28958413
    9   Gm21149 5   11594913    11599784    TRIL    7   28953358    28958413
```

Comment: `M. start` and `M. end` are the splitted version of the `Position` column but what about `H. Start` and `H. End`. from where they bob up?

Comment: I guess your last row in the expected output is not show n in the input dataset

Comment: @SabDeM.. The new table is arranged based on the unique  Gene.ID and Common.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We could use the `devel` version of 'data.table' ie. `v1.9.5`.  Instructions to install are [`here`](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation).

We change the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`).  Using the `tstrsplit`, we split the 'Position' by all non-numeric characters (`[^0-9]+`) to create new columns ('Chr', 'start', 'end').

```
library(data.table)#v1.9.5+
DT <- setDT(df1)[, c('Chr', 'start', 'end') :=tstrsplit(Position, '[^0-9]+')[-1]]
```

Create an sequence column ('ind') grouped by 'GeneID' and 'Common'

```
DT[, ind:=1:.N, .(GeneID, Common)]
```

`dcast` from the devel version can take multiple `value.var` columns and change the 'long' format to 'wide' format.  We can replace the NA values by the non-NA value in the dataset.

```
dcast(DT, GeneID+ind~substr(Common, 1, 1), value.var=names(DT)[c(4,6:8)])[,
 lapply(.SD, function(x) x[!is.na(x)]) , GeneID, .SDcols=h_Name:m_end]
#    GeneID h_Name  m_Name h_Chr m_Chr  h_start  m_start    h_end    m_end
#1:      3  ACADM   Acadm     5     5 15028950 26082574 15032998 26089291
#2:      6  ACAT1   Acat1     5     5 15471699 25999022 15477027 26004798
#3:      7    NLN      NA     5    NA 26257691       NA 26264308       NA
#4:      8     NA  canct1    NA     5       NA 14910122       NA 14914899
#5:      9   TRIL Gm10220     7     5 28953358 25936465 28958413 25943267
#6:      9   TRIL Gm10354     7     5 28953358 25949797 28958413 25954344
#7:      9   TRIL  Gm1979     7     5 28953358 11594913 28958413 11599784
```

Comment: @akrun.this command looks bit complicated for me. Could you please describe it

Comment: @akrun loved the use of `tstrsplit` in your answer and upgraded to `devel` version! (+1)

Comment: @beginner  As I explained in the code, the first set of code, creates the 3 columns from a single column by using `tstrsplit`, in the second code block, create the sequence column (ind) for the grouping variables and in the third, we convert the 'long' form to 'wide' format with `dcast`.  After we changed the 'wide' format, some columns have `NA` values as they don't have corresponding row combination for the group.  So, we change the NA values to the non-NA value in that column (`lapply(.SD, function(x) x[!is.na(x)])`  If you mention where you have difficulty, I can go over it.

Comment: @akrun.Thank you. tstrsplit function was new for me and very useful. I did not understand how the colnames was assigned for human and mouse (Chr_h,Chr_m,start_h, start_m..etc)

Comment: @beginner the `trsplit` output here is 4 columns of which the first one is an empty column, which I removed by `tstrsplit(Position, '[^0-9]+')[-1]`.   The new columns were created with column names `c('Chr', 'start', 'end')`.  When we do the `dcast`, `~substr(Common, 1, 1)`, the first character of 'Common' is extracted with `substr` and that gives the`_m` or `_h` here.

Answer (score 4):

Another option using `lapply`

```
# using split method from akrun's answer
library(data.table)#v1.9.5+
DT <- setDT(df1)[, c('Chr', 'start', 'end') :=tstrsplit(Position, '[^0-9]+')[-1]]

out = setDF(Reduce(function(...) merge(..., by="GeneID", all = T),
            lapply(split(DT, DT$Common), 
            function(x) subset(x, select = -c(Common, Position, Organism)))))  

colnames(out) = gsub("x", "H", colnames(out)) 
colnames(out) = gsub("y", "M", colnames(out))

#> out
#  GeneID Name.H Chr.H  start.H    end.H  Name.M Chr.M  start.M    end.M
#1      3  ACADM     5 15028950 15032998   Acadm     5 26082574 26089291
#2      6  ACAT1     5 15471699 15477027   Acat1     5 25999022 26004798
#3      7    NLN     5 26257691 26264308    <NA>  <NA>     <NA>     <NA>
#4      8   <NA>  <NA>     <NA>     <NA>  canct1     5 14910122 14914899
#5      9   TRIL     7 28953358 28958413 Gm10220     5 25936465 25943267
#6      9   TRIL     7 28953358 28958413 Gm10354     5 25949797 25954344
#7      9   TRIL     7 28953358 28958413  Gm1979     5 11594913 11599784
```